# Stop filtered emails from downloading with POP?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm using a POP3 client to download the email from my Gmail account, but I don't want **all** of the email, just the unfiltered email.

Specifically, I receive an email every time a customer purchases from my website.  I have a filter set up which finds the merchant emails, and sorts them into an "Auto-Sorted" label.  It also marks them as read and "Skip the Inbox".

Is there any way to prevent this from being downloaded via POP3?

Just in case you're wondering, no, IMAP isn't an option.