# Gmail filter to disable POP for specific messages

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a filter in place for certain messages I don't want to be made available via POP. I don't want to delete them but I don't want them downloaded via POP either.

The current filter is "skip the inbox/archive it", but that doesn't prevent them from being downloaded.

**Is there a filter option that will accomplish this? Or is there an add-on filter app that will enable more robust filtering (a la Outlook)?**

Comment: This is my own question, but it is a possible duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/34061/16932